# App doesn't catch powermode changes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

at first I want to say hello for all users. I'm a newbie at .NET programming. I have a problem with Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs class. My app is supposed to detect if system is going to sleep state and when system is resume from sleep.

```
    Sub main()
    If count = 0 Then
        If close = False Then
            firstrun()
        End If
        Dim start As New Thread(AddressOf specials)
        start.Start()
        Dim watch As New Thread(AddressOf watchdog)
        watch.Start()
        If close = True Then
            start.Abort()
            watch.Abort()
        End If
    End If
    Do Until close = True
        Thread.Sleep(20)
        'do something
    Loop
    RemoveHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, AddressOf PowerModeChange
    RemoveHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding, AddressOf SessionEnding
    Application.Exit()
    End
    End Sub

    Sub PowerModeChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Win32.PowerModeChangedEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Mode
            Case Microsoft.Win32.PowerModes.Suspend And sus = False
                sus = True
                res = False
                status = "System suspended "
                count = 0
                firstrun()
            Case Microsoft.Win32.PowerModes.StatusChange And res = False
                res = True
                sus = False
                status = "System resumed "
                count = 0
                firstrun()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Sub watchdog()
             AddHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, AddressOf PowerModeChange
             AddHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding, AddressOf SessionEnding
    End Sub
```

This is small part of my code. Unfortunately code is working perfectly when debugging in Visual Studio 2010. But when compiled and running as standalone exe, is not detecting power states. As you can see, I tried to add handles in another thread, tried also to loop that thread but without success. My app is kind of service running in background. Maybe You can help to beginner programmer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is you application truly a windows service? Or are you just running the application, but leaving it "in the background"?
When you run your application (outside of Visual Studio), is it running as you? Or another user?

Comment: The documentation for the [power mode events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) mentions you need to run it inside a Form.

Comment: @hometoast : A Windows Service usually doesn't contain `Sub Main()`. My guess is that it is either a Console Application or a WinForms Application that doesn't show any form.

Comment: This app isn't a trully service. This is a console application intended to run in background, in Application Type I selected Windows Form mainly because I don't want my app to show anything, only running in background. This is why I have in my app sub main. Regardless to PC or user, when I running my app inside visual studio, my app works as intended, but not work as standalone app, neither on quest account nor on admin account. Thanks for replies. :D

Comment: Put the `<MTAThread>` attribute on your Main() method so the SystemEvents class won't think that you wrote a Winforms app that pumps a message loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for replies. This solution helps and now app work flawlessly. Thank you very much.

```
<MTAThread()> _
Sub Main()
    'doing something
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for replies. This solution helps and now app work. But handling seems to remove after resume and not working. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, handling seems to remove after raising event or resume and not working (Event is raising only one time, regardless of kind of powermode event. For example, if my app is detecting when system comes to sleep, after resume is not detecting resume. And when I plug off my pc, app detects StatusChange, but only one time). Any advice? Thanks in advance.